# plot a histogram over specific columns of a dataframe pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe with a cloumn called rel_positive, and a column called len_text_celaned
I want to plot a histogramm where rel_positive is displayed as a function of len_text_celaned.

I tried it with this straightforward approach:

```
df_rel.rel_positive.hist(df_rel.len_text_celaned)
```

As far as I understand the first argument in the brackets of df.hist is the x-values?
but it returns me an array rather than a plot.

```
array([[<matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x0000020AF0104630>,
        <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x0000020AF48A4EF0>,
```

Maybe I'm overseeing a very stupid mistake, or is there another way?

EDIT:
Apparently it looks like the array contains several lists.

Comment: Are you working in a Jupyter Notebook? If so, try running the IPython magic command `%matplotlib inline`, then running your plotting code again.

Comment: yes i do, after calling your command i still get the same results..

Answer (score 0):

According to pandas documentation ([pandas.DataFrame.hist()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.hist.html)), the first argument is `column`:

- **column**:  *string* or *sequence*. If passed, will be used to limit data to a subset of columns.

I will give an example based in your question:

```
import pandas as pd
df_rel = pd.DataFrame({'rel_positive': ['Y', 'N', 'Y', 'N', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'N', 'N', 'Y'] ,
                   'len_text_celaned': [3,1,2,1,3,5,2,3,4,4]})
df_rel.len_text_celaned.hist(df_rel.rel_positive)
```

Since the `rel_positive` column has 2 values ('Y' or 'N'), the  `df_rel.len_text_celaned.hist(column=df_rel.rel_positive)` will plot 1 histogram for each `rel_positive` value, with the referred `len_text_celaned` values.

[Check the resulting plot in this link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0M00b.jpg)

Comment: ah that explains why i only get the array... but still how can i then solve my problem?

Comment: Try to plot the first index, like df_rel.len_text_celaned.hist(df_rel.rel_positive)[0]. Check if it works

Comment: no doesnt work, i get an array of one list returned, looks like the one provided above